# Calling AWS Services from a container on ECS + EC2. Connection Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I want to run an ECS Task on EC2 instance, and I want that task/container to be able to call other AWS services via Boto3.

When I run the same task on Fargate, it works as expected and I am able to call other AWS services from the task/container. When I run the ECS Task on EC2, it given me connection timeout errors when attempting to call other AWS services. (The specific errors depend on the service.)

In an attempt to rule out any permission issues, I am running in a public subnet and using a single IAM role (with the AdministratorAccess policy) for the EC2 instance, ECS task role, and ECS task execution role.

<strike>The ECS Task on EC2 IS able to access the internet (which I confirmed by having it ping google.com).</strike>

**What are any other conditions that need to be satisfied in order to call other AWS services from a container on ECS + EC2?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of my issue was using a public subnet and the awsvpc network mode.

> Using Amazon EC2 — You can launch EC2 instances on a public subnet.
> Amazon ECS uses these EC2 instances as cluster capacity, and any
> containers that are running on the instances can use the underlying
> public IP address of the host for outbound networking. This applies to
> both the host and bridge network modes. **However, the awsvpc network
> mode doesn't provide task ENIs with public IP addresses. Therefore,
> they can’t make direct use of an internet gateway.**
> -- [Amazon Elastic Container Service Best Practices Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-outbound.html)